# Is there a faster way to refresh my module changes?

Tags: azerothcore

I am using a module called `TimeIsTime` (https://www.azerothcore.org/catalogue-details.html?id=342405971) to accelerate the day/night cycle in game.

So far, I made some changes on it for my own usage, but each time I had to recompile my worldserver to get the changes recorded, is there a faster way ?
I saw someone use the `reload [modulename]` command in the worldserver prompt to refresh it at runtime, but I didn't managed to get the same result.

I had no luck trying to find the information on the Wiki page.

Any solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any changes to the source code of a C++ module require a full re-run of cmake and a clean build. There is no way to bypass this that i am aware of.

As an alternative the Eluna engine allows the execution of Lua code which can be changed and loaded at runtime.